# Return of the Activity on Android

Tags: android

Activity A creates Activity B using Intent (A does not call finish()). If the user clicks Back Button of Activity B to return to Activity A, how to restore all the states (values and UI content) of Activity A at the moment of creating B?

onSaveInstanceState() seems not the solution.

I tried onSaveInstanceState() in A, but once returning to A, A goes from onCreate() with the condition (savedInstanceState != null) never being true. Basically, it does not read what is saved in onSaveInstanceState(), although it probably should.

Also tried android:launchMode="singleTop" in Manifests of A, no effect.

I guess this is because appcompatactivity back (UP) button destroys the parent activity. Android back button does not.

Comment: Did you destroy your activity while switching to other activity ?

Comment: When you will return ti to activity it will restart or resumed in your case it will resumed please refer official{https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html}

Comment: In your case, you should use fragments instead of Activities. use Fragments with BackStackManager

Comment: you might be calling finish() after startActivity(intent) while going from Activity A to B , remove that method call.
If possible, share your activity code

Comment: I did not call finish() after startActivity().

Comment: are you talking about the hardware back button or the one we add to the toolbar ?

Comment: Appcompatactivity one causes problems. The hardware one is fine.

Comment: @CLuo try calling onBackPressed() when the user clicks the back button on the toolbar.

Comment: Many thanks. Still not sure how to write proper statements in onBackPressed().

Comment: you must be using NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); Please share the code you are using to go back to the previous page. I will try to help

Comment: I did not implement anything with the back/Up button. Appcompatactivity handles it by default.

Comment: you can change how the button behaves. Check this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Extended-ActionBar-Guide#navigating-up-with-the-app-icon